# Return only uppercase SMTP entries in get-aduser proxyaddresses

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to return only the entries with uppercase SMTP in proxyaddresses.  So far this is what I have:

```
get-aduser user.name -pr proxyaddresses |select proxyaddresses |? {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'}
```

Comment: "capital smtp"? You mean "uppercase"?

Answer (score 6):

You don't really ask a question, so I'm going to infer a bit here. Either all you want is the ProxyAddress, or you want users where the ProxyAddress has upper case SMTP in it.

If all you want is the ProxyAddress then you were really close. Instead of just selecting the property with your `Select` command, you need to use the `-ExpandProperty` argument so that it expands that property and passes the values down the pipeline.

```
get-aduser user.name -pr proxyaddresses |select -ExpandProperty proxyaddresses |? {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP'}
```

If you want to get the users, and only check for the proxyaddress as an aside, you would skip the `Select`, and then specify the property in your `Where` statement as such:

```
get-aduser user.name -pr proxyaddresses |? {$_.proxyaddresses -cmatch '^SMTP'}
```

Comment: that did it, i was missing the expand property....i thought I didn't need that because the results showed all the proxyaddresses already, guess I was wrong, thanks for the help